# POST request pending when data is added

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, post

I've never experienced something like this before; I hadn't worked on this project for a bit and all of the sudden I couldn't get any POST route to work anymore, all GET routes were still handled just fine - after doing a lot of debugging I removed the sent along data from the request, and for some reason the route started working again.

**Example**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/user/test',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(true)
  }, error: console.log });
```

Server would log a request being made just fine with the above. However after adding the data attribute;

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/user/test',
    data: {
      1: 2
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(true)
    }, error: console.log 
  });
```

XHR request is now pending (forever till the server displays POST /user/test - - ms - -)  with the above code, changed nothing to the route at all;

```
router.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('test')
  res.send('done');
});
```

What could it be?

**Requests**

Example of pending request when adding data to the request
[image: Example of pending request when adding data to the request]

Example of successful request when not adding data
[image: Example of successful request when not adding data]

Comment: There is really nothing in the code that you have shared that could be causing this as far as I can tell. My best guess is some middleware higher up in the chain is not calling `next()` when the data is populated in your POST request

Comment: set the content-type header

Comment: @ChiragRavindra is there anything else I could share? there's quite as lot of files within the project. Also; I am not seeing any missing `next()` within my middleware, but it should also have an impact on other routes - which still work, right?

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Well, yeah I do have a body parser, but, well, turns out you were right; after looking for multiple hours it turns out one of my recently added middleware that involved posted data didn't have the required next() function called.

Comment: @MartijnEbbens Haha those are hard to catch :) Pending requests are usually a good sign that `res.send()` was never called

Comment: thats weird, just tested your url it returns "done" on the response.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `sendStatus(200)` from the server to the request and it will be fine, `send()` only works for data sending not for status.